How to get default banner notifitications back (Black rounded banner notifications on Android 14)
After having played around with settings to setup my phone better, my banner notifications have changed style:

I've searched for "notification" and gone through all settings to try and figure it out, but after having spend an hour going through menus I'm non the wiser. The "new/black rounded" banners have no action buttons so they are quite useless.
I'm on a Zenfone 9 running Android 14.
